# selecting default value for dropdown in angular

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I am using angular for development. 
 when age is between 18 and 19 credit score hides and not for more than 19.

```
 <select id="autoInsuranceStatus" name="autoInsuranceStatus" ng-model="namedInsured.autoInsuranceStatus" ng-options="m.key as m.value for m in vm.currentInsuranceList" required style="width: 250px;">
                            <option value="">Select insurance status</option>
                        </select>
```

So now for initially its showing correct and hides as I want. But when I go to next page with age 18 and 19 and with hep of back button come back and change age more than 19 than it took last element by default.

I tried ng-init, $scope.namedInsured.autoInsuranceStatus=0 and many others by no luck .

Can you help me with that?

Comment: try $scope.namedInsured.autoInsuranceStatus="" (I mean empty)

Comment: I tried that , that's not working as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. So I put watch on birthdate and there I put 
          $scope.namedInsured.creditScore = 0;

So when I change my birthdate it initialize dropdown for creditscore

Answer (score 0):

Need to set the value on `$scope` from the array of objects that are going into the select dropdown. Something like :

```
$scope.namedInsured.autoInsuranceStatus = vm.currentInsuranceList[0]
```

Comment: Elements 0 to 4 are values that are main value that are populating, so that's not an option